# Simple application for the game "Mad Lib"

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, dom, twitter-bootstrap

It is an application for the game "Mad Lib". I decided to use bootstrap modal for the questions.

Mad libs are a simple game where you create a story template with blanks for words. You, or another player, then construct a list of words and place them into the story, creating an often silly or funny story as a result.

I will appreciate any advice about the code.

```js
$(function(){
        const nounInput = $('#noun-input');
 const verbInput = $('#verb-input');
 const adjInput = $('#adjective-input');
 const adverbInput = $('#adverb-input');
 const sent = $('#sentence');
 var nounDisplay = "";
 var verbDisplay = "";
 var adjDisplay = "";
 var adverbDisplay = "";
 $('#first').click(function(){
  nounDisplay = nounInput.val();
 });
 $('#second').click(function(){
  verbDisplay = verbInput.val();
 });
 $('#third').click(function(){
  adjDisplay = adjInput.val();
 });
 $('#fourth').click(function(){
  adverbDisplay = adverbInput.val();
  sent.text("Do you " + nounDisplay + " your " + adjDisplay + " " + nounDisplay + adjDisplay + "? That's hilarious!")
 });

  });
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<!--main content-->
<div class="container rounded mt-2 mb-2 pt-5 pb-5 text-center">
 <h2>Mad Lib</h2>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#first_modal">Let's game!</button>
</div>

<!--first-modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="first_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="first_modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="first_modalLabel">Enter a noun:</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="noun-input">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="first" data-dismiss="modal"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#second_modal">Next step</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--second-modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="second_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="second_modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="second_modalLabel">Enter a verb:</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="verb-input">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="second" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#third_modal">Next step</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--third-modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="third_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="third_modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="third_modalLabel">Enter an adjective:</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adjective-input">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="third" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fourth_modal">Next step</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--fourth-modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="fourth_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fourth_modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="fourth_modalLabel">Enter an adverb:</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adverb-input">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="fourth" data-dismiss="modal">Finish!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Output sentence-->
<h3 class="text-center mt-1 mb-2" id="sentence"></h3>


 
</body>
```

Comment: `"Do you " + nounDisplay + " your " + adjDisplay + " " + nounDisplay + adjDisplay` is not likely to form a grammatically correct sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Feedback

The code does cache DOM references (which I know we have mentioned in your other posts) using `const`.

All lines appear to have a semi-colon to end the line, except the one where text content is updated (i.e. `sent.text(...)`). While it isn't required to have one, it would be wise to be consistent, for the sake of anyone who reads your code/might need to alter it.

### Suggestions

#### Using `let` instead of `var`

If you are going to use `const`, which not then use `let` for the mutable strings instead of `var`?

#### Setting values

Instead of making four click handlers, you could just use the last one to set the values, since the DOM elements are all still present despite not being visible. That way, those variables can have the scope be limited to a single function, and then `const` can be used there:

```
$('#fourth').click(function() {
    const nounDisplay = nounInput.val();
    const adjDisplay = adjInput.val();
    const verbDisplay = verbInput.val();
    const adverbDisplay = adverbInput.val();
    sent.text("Do you " + nounDisplay + " your " + adjDisplay + " " + nounDisplay + adjDisplay + "? That's hilarious!")
  });
```

#### Mixing markup with display logic

This is just a minor point and likely not something to worry about but some might argue that having the markup control logic (e.g. `data-target` on the *Next Step* buttons) might be considered tight coupling, but perhaps that is just the idiomatic way for those modals to be laid out.